# Python MemoryError on large array

Tags: python, memory

**This is the python script that I'm trying to run:**

```
n = 50000000000 ##50 billion 
b = [0]*n
for x in range(0,n):
    b[x] = random.randint(1,899999)
```

... But the output I'm getting is:

```
E:\python\> python sort.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\sort.py", line 8, in <module>
    b = [0]*n
MemoryError
```

So, what do I do now?

Comment: You're out of memory. The error message says so.

Comment: You are trying to allocate a 40GB array

Comment: An `int` takes at least 24 bytes; you have 5,000,000,000 `int`s. That's 111GB right there.

Comment: Maybe it would be more useful if you explained what you were planning to do with so many random numbers. Almost certainly there's a way to do it without blowing out your memory.

Comment: @chepner ints in python seems to be 64 bits, so 8 bytes. 24 bytes would be one heck of a number

Comment: @litelite No, an `int` is a Python object, representing an integer with arbitrary precision, not a machine word.

Comment: That's right, Python has overhead in order to keep track of types etc. You want an 8-byte int, use C.

Comment: @chepner Right, not a pro in python I keep forgeting about that

Comment: Also you counted your zeros wrong, so n is 50 billion, not 5 billion.

Comment: Also, ints in Python are not even 64 bits; Python has unlimited-length integers, welcome to the modern world.

Comment: @alexis or `numpy`, or `array.array`

Comment: You mean to limit the memory footprint? Good point. Though the `struct` option isn't actually an `int`, it's just cargo...

Comment: Even if you *have* a terabyte of free memory, there's no need to initialize the list with zeros first; just use `b = [random.randint(1,899999) for _ in range(n)]`.

Comment: @chepner well, in CPython at least, initializing with all zeros will be using the cached `0` object.

Comment: if not python3 use `xrange` and listen to the comments above, what is the purpose of initalizing a list with zero?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size of the list you are generating (which is 50 billion not 5).

An `int` object instance takes 24 bytes (`sys.getsizeof(int(899999))`, the upper limit of your random numbers), so that list would take `50,000,000,000 * 24 bytes`, which is about **1.09 TB**.

In other words to create such a list you would need at least **1118 GB of RAM** in your computer.

I don't know what your use case is, but you should consider a different approach to what you are trying to solve (maybe define a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), or just don't store your numbers in memory and instead directly use the numbers in the for loop).

Comment: That's actually a *lower limit* generally. The smallest `int` takes that much, but `int` objects take variable amounts of memory, e.g. `sys.getsizeof(1000000000000000000) == 32`, whereas `sys.getsizeof(1000) == 28`,

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In the author's question, the maximum attainable number is 899999, and int objects from 0 up to that number are all 24 bytes in size. (I updated the answer to show how this upper limit is calculated)

Comment: I'm getting 28 on my system... 64bit python 3.5, Mac OSX

Comment: Python 3 apparently has 4 more bytes of overhead compared to Python 2

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga For zero, you don't need to store any data. For anything with a larger magnitude, you need to store something.

Comment: Also, just to pile on, we've only been talking about the memory needed for the `int` objects themselves. The *list* is another 64 bytes plus 50,000,000,000 pointers (4-8 bytes, depending on your architecture) to reference each `int` object.

Answer (score 2):

Since other people already answered your question here's a quick tip when dealing with big numbers: you can use "_" to separate the digits of your numbers as you wish:

```
n = 50_000_000_000
```

is the same as

```
n = 50000000000
```

but the former is much easier on the eyes

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility is to increase you computers vitual memory. It helped me in my code. I had a max 3000MB virtual memory, when I increased it to 5000MB the memory error was gone.